# Asynchronous execution of Python subprocess.Popen with wait()

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, popen

I'm new to Python async concepts. However I want to sequentially call 2 functions, the order is what matters here:

```py
def func1():
    p = subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -i in.webm out.mp4')
    p.wait()

def func2():
    os.remove('in.webm')

func1()
func2()
```

Function 1 contains subprocess which converts video files, and function 2 deletes the input afterwards.
`Popen` with `p.wait()` does force synchronous execution but it comes at the price of blocking the main thread.
`Popen` without `p.wait()` doesn't block it but makes function 2 to get called before ffmpeg will complete its job.

I would like to achieve something similar to Javascript promises or async/await constructs like this:

```js
async func1() {
    let response = await fetch('/api');
    let user = await response.json();
    return user;
}

func2(func1());
```

Sounds like a trivial task but I'm lost between multithreading, multiprocessing and asyncio.
How can I make function 2 to await for the output of function 1 without blocking the main thread?

Comment: You could let the shell do it for you if `ffmpeg` runs successfully with `ffmpeg -i in.webm out.mp4 && rm in.webm`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to get the concept, ffmpeg is purely for demo purposes

Comment: In your JS example, `func2` receives a promise, which it must await if it wants to obtain "user". You also didn't specify if `func2`  is sync or async. Can you please flesh out the JS example, otherwise it's not obvious (to me) what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @user4815162342 The question is How can I make function 2 to await for the output of function 1 without blocking the main thread? Think of this: fetch('api').then(res => console.log(res.json())). How to achieve the same in Python?

Comment: The main thread will always be blocked because it is presumably running the asyncio event loop. But the _event loop_ won't be blocked because it will be able to run other tasks. Just like JavaScrpit, asyncio is single-threaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To spawn subprocesses in an asyncio program, use [asyncio's subprocess primitives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) which provide an interface similar to that of `subprocess`, but exposing awaitable coroutines.

The equivalent of your JavaScript example would be something like this:

```
async def main():
    # Schedule func1() to run, but don't await it. (In JavaScript
    # it would be enough to just call func1().)
    asyncio.create_task(func1())

    print('we get here immediately')

    # Await something to keep the event loop spinning - without
    # this, the program would exit at this point. In real code
    # this would await an exit signal, server.wait_closed(), etc.
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

async def func1():
    # Like in JavaScript, await suspends the current function
    # until a result is available.
    res = await fetch('/api1', {})
    userid = (await res.json()).id
    asyncio.create_task(func2(userid))

async def func2(userid):
    res = await fetch('/api2', ...userid...)
    func3((await res.json()).url)

def func3(url):
    print('user photo', url)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please describe what is going on under the hood? Is it based on multithreading underneath it or multiprocessing or neither of it?

Comment: @Igniter Neither. It's single-threaded and cooperative, much like the one in JavaScript. In Python the implementation uses generators under the hood, see e.g. [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JtNiwCH_OA) for details.

Comment: Got it, very interesting! But how do you call func2 within main() using as its args the actual output of func1? I mean instead of sleep(50) how do you use `user` data from func1 for calling func2?

Comment: @Igniter You can define a `func3` that does `x = await func1(); func2(x)` and call `create_task(func3())` in `main`. As for your second question, normally you'd just `await func1()`, but I your requirement was that the main thread continues running. Since `main()` represents an (async version of the) main thread, I made it sleep so the program doesn't exit immediately.

Comment: Something similar to this? https://pastebin.com/VLv01stK

Comment: @Igniter Sorry but it's again not clear what you're trying to achieve - can you please write the JavaScript equivalent of that code? As written, the program will exit immediately because `main()` starts two background tasks and returns without awaiting either of them (or doing anything else, such as `await sleep()` in my example). Also, it's unclear why you create two separate tasks, since `func3` invokes `func1` to begin with. Without a clear goal, we are running in circles.

Comment: Yep, this is the pseudo JS code: https://pastebin.com/K72QTRTT

Comment: @Igniter I can translate that to Python, but it will not be idiomatic. Could you use await in the JavaScript version, like you did in the question?

Comment: Sure, here it is, thanks for your help: https://pastebin.com/jeiuQpzL

Comment: @Igniter I've amended the answer with a translation and a reminder to use the asyncio subprocess functionality inside an asyncio program, not the regular `subprocess`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think there is a typo. You say `fun2` but it is actually `func2`